# No base case for binary tree reversal?

Tags: binary-tree

Why doesn't the following Python code for reversing a binary tree need a base case?

```
def invertTree(root):
    if root:
        root.left, root.right = invertTree(root.right), invertTree(root.left)
    return root
```

where the node is defined as

```
class TreeNode:
 def __init__(self, x):
     self.val = x
     self.left = None
     self.right = None
```

?

Comment: The `if root` kinda handles the base case by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case is when `if: root` evaluates to false. For instance when you call `invertTree(root.right)`, if `root.right` does not exist, then in the `invertTree` call `if: root` will evaluate to false, and the function will return without calling `invertTree` again.